# Spring Hibernate Application takes a lot of time to start on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate, tomcat

I am writing a simple *Spring / Hibernate* application which has to query a remote *Oracle 12* database and return a row of data.

The issue is that the *Tomcat* server is taking a lot of time to startup and never does when launched through *Eclipse*.

It gets stuck in the logs given below:

```
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Sep 22, 2017 6:57:55 PM         org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl    makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Sep 22, 2017 6:57:56 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource 
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 2vkgsu9q1b3tesb1o3y14g|38bd327a, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 2vkgsu9q1b3tesb1o3y14g|38bd327a, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:oracle:thin:@remus.corp.apple.com:1529:gsxt, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 30000, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
Sep 22, 2017 6:57:56 PM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
WARNING: Bad pool size config, start 3 < min 5. Using 5 as start.
```

Note that I have already set below property in *Hibernate* config xml :

```
<prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
```

The source code is available in a [Git repository](https://github.com/vishwabhat19/LongStartupApp.git).

Comment: in your servlet, you should give your package name in `<context:component-scan base-package="src" />` i.e. `<context:component-scan base-package="com.gsx"/>`

Comment: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GSX_Hibernate]]

Comment: This just gives me these exceptions:org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GSX_Hibernate]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)

Comment: adding com.gsx as your scan package gives you this exception???

Comment: Could you add your database pool connection configuration?

Comment: No sorry, this was due to some issue with Git.  But no, this doesn't solve the problem. :)

Comment: I am really sorry.I am unable to add this here, but the same is present in the Spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml and this is present in the https://github.com/vishwabhat19/LongStartupApp.git